# IntelOMP and LLVM OMP colliding

Tags: python, ubuntu, conda, openmp

We have a conda environment that apparently causes issues when running:

```
/opt/miniconda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/threadpoolctl.py:546: RuntimeWarning: 
Found Intel OpenMP ('libiomp') and LLVM OpenMP ('libomp') loaded at
the same time. Both libraries are known to be incompatible and this
can cause random crashes or deadlocks on Linux when loaded in the
same Python program.
```

I tried to figure out which package requires LLVM OpenMP:

```
grep llvm ~/anaconda3/pkgs/*/info/index.json
/home/user/anaconda3/pkgs/libclang-10.0.1-default_hb85057a_2/info/index.json:    "libllvm10 >=10.0.1,<10.1.0a0",
/home/user/anaconda3/pkgs/libllvm10-10.0.1-hbcb73fb_5/info/index.json:  "name": "libllvm10",
/home/user/anaconda3/pkgs/libllvm11-11.1.0-h9e868ea_6/info/index.json:  "name": "libllvm11",
/home/user/anaconda3/pkgs/libllvm14-14.0.6-hdb19cb5_3/info/index.json:  "name": "libllvm14",
/home/user/anaconda3/pkgs/llvmlite-0.39.1-py310he621ea3_0/info/index.json:    "libllvm11 >=11.1.0,<11.2.0a0",
/home/user/anaconda3/pkgs/llvmlite-0.39.1-py310he621ea3_0/info/index.json:  "name": "llvmlite",
/home/user/anaconda3/pkgs/llvmlite-0.40.0-py310he621ea3_0/info/index.json:    "libllvm14 >=14.0.6,<14.1.0a0",
/home/user/anaconda3/pkgs/llvmlite-0.40.0-py310he621ea3_0/info/index.json:  "name": "llvmlite",
/home/user/anaconda3/pkgs/numba-0.56.4-py310h1128e8f_0/info/index.json:    "llvmlite >=0.39.*,<0.40",
/home/user/anaconda3/pkgs/numba-0.57.0-py310h1128e8f_0/info/index.json:    "libllvm14 >=14.0.6,<14.1.0a0",
/home/user/anaconda3/pkgs/numba-0.57.0-py310h1128e8f_0/info/index.json:    "llvmlite >=0.40.0,<0.41.0a0",
/home/user/anaconda3/pkgs/pynndescent-0.5.10-py310h06a4308_0/info/index.json:    "llvmlite >=0.34",
```

Other parts of the packages explicitly use Intel OpenMP:

```
grep intel ~/anaconda3/pkgs/*/info/index.json
/home/user/anaconda3/pkgs/intel-openmp-2021.4.0-h06a4308_3561/info/index.json:  "name": "intel-openmp",
/home/user/anaconda3/pkgs/intel-openmp-2023.1.0-hdb19cb5_46305/info/index.json:  "name": "intel-openmp",
/home/user/anaconda3/pkgs/mkl-2021.4.0-h06a4308_640/info/index.json:    "intel-openmp 2021.*"
/home/user/anaconda3/pkgs/mkl-2023.1.0-h6d00ec8_46342/info/index.json:    "intel-openmp 2023.*",
/home/user/anaconda3/pkgs/pytorch-1.12.1-cpu_py310hb1f1ab4_1/info/index.json:    "intel-openmp >=2021.4.0,<2022.0a0",
/home/user/anaconda3/pkgs/scikit-learn-intelex-2023.0.2-py310h06a4308_0/info/index.json:  "name": "scikit-learn-intelex",
/home/user/anaconda3/pkgs/scipy-1.10.0-py310hd5efca6_1/info/index.json:    "intel-openmp >=2021.4.0,<2022.0a0",
/home/user/anaconda3/pkgs/scipy-1.10.1-py310h5f9d8c6_1/info/index.json:    "intel-openmp >=2023.1.0,<2024.0a0",
```

How can I avoid this issue with two different OpenMPs used?

Comment: Definitely a bug that needs patching in package metadata. Please add info to existing issue: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/13146

Comment: Instead of grepping around in `pkgs` (the package cache) could do you instead do that in `conda-meta` (where the info for what is installed in the environment is saved). Better, use `mamba repoquery whoneeds llvm-openmp` etc. to get more specific info.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall or Disable One OpenMP Library:
Depending on your requirements and the source of the conflict, you may choose to uninstall or disable one of the OpenMP libraries. For example, if you are not explicitly using Intel OpenMP, you may uninstall it.

For Conda ------->

```
conda uninstall libiomp
conda uninstall libomp
```

For pip------>

```
pip uninstall intel-openmp
pip uninstall llvmlite
```